# Can I change grip on a two-handed weapon if it's not my turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, action-economy

Picture this scenario: I am standing in front of an enemy, brandishing my massive, two-handed greataxe. I expect the enemy to flee, and am already salivating at the opportunity attack I shall unleash.

But then! Shock and horror! I am attacked by a dozen other opponents, for massive amounts of damage! Clearly the proper way out is to use the *shield* spell... but wait! It has a somatic component, and both of my hands are firmly on the haft of my axe. Is this the end of our greedy hero?

But no, clearly I should anticipate this course of action, and instead of readying my weapon, I should keep one hand free... but then! My quarry might flee, since I cannot attack with the weapon I have!

... of course, this is all moot if, in fact, I *can* change the way I hold my weapon if it is not my turn, but the crux of the question is, can I?

Comment: Note this question is also important—and contentious—in D&D 3.5e. The rules don’t satisfactorily address it in that edition; it’s therefore not certain that they will in 5e. Hoping they do, though.

Comment: Related: [Does switching between using a versatile weapon one-handed to two-handed cost anything with regards to the action economy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162923/33569), [Are you considered to have a free hand while using a Versatile weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59930/33569), [Can you cast spells with a Somatic component if you're holding a two-handed weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51994/33569) - Let us know if any of these questions (or another linked question) matches yours and answers it.

Comment: Very related (possibly duplicates in these): "[Can a character drop a weapon in order to cast a spell that is a reaction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59124)" and "[Action economies, two-handed weapons, and spells with Somatic components](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53033)"

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, your situation here is one of the cases covered by the linked dupe target. If the answers don't satisfy you, I recommend setting a bounty there.